# iPhone/iPad viewpoint changes on portrait and landscape

Tags: javascript, html, ios, orientation, metadata

I am trying to make a site resize for iPad and iPhone using separate meta viewpoint data.

So far this is what I am using:

```
<meta id="viewport" name='viewport'>
<script>
    (function(doc) {
        var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
        if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
            doc.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "initial-scale=0.3");
        } else if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ) {
            doc.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "initial-scale=0.7");
        }
    }(document));
</script>
```

and its working pretty well. the only problem is I need the scales to differ when the device is made portrait/landscape as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CSS definition of a media query.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation)

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

You could e.g. use different stylesheets depending on the orientation where you can set the scaling:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” media=”all and (orientation:portrait)” href=”css/portrait.css”>
<link rel=”stylesheet” media=”all and (orientation:landscape)” href=”css/landscape.css”>
```

Comment: but that would mean creating new css files for portrait and landscape and resizing everything etc. The script I am already using works quite well, I was just wondering if there is a navigator.userAgent.match that picks up if the device is in landscape or portrait so I could have the scale change with orientation.

Comment: You don't need to create new files, it was just an example of how you could separate the styling. You can also specify the scaling inside the `...` part of my answer.